# Iterating over an array with Array.FindAll( )

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to return a subset of records from an array based on date.

My code looks like this:

```
var SomeAccounts = Array.FindAll(Accounts, x => x.modification_date > modification_date);

if (SomeAccounts == null)
{
    return NotFound();
}

return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SomeAccounts));
```

The Accounts array has a modification_date field but what comes back is all the accounts. In my test sample, 2 have mod dates > May 15, 2016. This kind of code works for other fields, but not for the date which is just:

```
public DateTime modification_date { get; set; }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Start with iterating it to see if it somehow breaks at Serialize.  Break it down to find out where they error originates.

Comment: Make sure your `DateTime` values are in the same time zone, and are of the same `.Kind`. Date comparison isn't as simple as it looks on the surface.

Comment: The returned array is never null, it is an empty array then. [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kkxfxdd(v=vs.110).aspx): _"An Array containing all the elements that match the conditions defined by the specified predicate, if found; otherwise, an empty Array."_

Comment: Before I reach Serialize I can see that SomeAccounts contains 7 records, the same as the number in Accounts, so it seems that none are excluded. As this just test data I've created I assume the time zones are the same. I changed the year to 2015 just in case. The comparison I use is 2015-05-12T15:15:20. So 2015-05-13 should be later, right?

Comment: Try to parse the two dates into a single format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ensuring That Your Array Is Actually Empty**

Firstly, the [`Array.FindAll()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kkxfxdd(v=vs.110).aspx) method should never actually return `null` as it will return an empty array if no matches are found, so you'll likely want to check to see if any values were found :

```
if (SomeAccounts.Length == 0)
{
    return NotFound();
}
```

If your results being returned were an array (with no values), then this would be correct (as it wouldn't have hit `NotFound()` previously as it was never null).

**Examining Dates**

As [Cory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74757/c%e1%b4%8f%ca%80%ca%8f) mentioned in a comment, comparing DateTime objects can be notoriously difficult. You are going to want to ensure that any information like TimeZones are taken into consideration when comparing the values.

You might also consider using the debugger to manually check to see how your `DateTime` objects look in code (both the `modification_date` property and your actual `modification_date` variable). Try comparing them in the Watch window to ensure the comparisons are working properly.

Comment: True. But doesn't really answer the question

Comment: Two of the modification dates are modification_date":"2015-05-13T15:15:19" I am comparing them to 5-12-2015 which comes in as 5-12-2015 12:00:00 AM. In the debugger, I cannot step further into FindAll(). That is I cannot see why the comparison always succeeds.

Comment: One way to troubleshoot the individiual comparisons would be to create Dictionary that mapped each Account to it's comparison value as seen [in this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/Rionmonster/2556850471d9c6a953d49cffd52ddbcd). If both of your comparison items are `DateTime` objects, then formatting shouldn't be an issue, but this should allow you to check each one individually.

Comment: It was the time offset. My comparison datetime was just 5-12-2015 but as I mentioned above it becomes 5-12-2015 12:00;00 AM and all the test dates were later than that. When I made two of the test dates 5-11-2015 it worked. But when I try to compare (in a browser on the address line) the browser treats the time as ports (the ":" ) and throws an exception.

Comment: You are going to want to encode those values if you are going to be using them within a querystring if you want them to work as expected.

Comment: enclose them how? I've tried adding    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" /> to web.config and I've tried using HTML escape sequences, but both fail.

Comment: If you are passing your date via the navigation bar for testing purposes, encode your value using something like [this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/), which would encode your `:` characters turning `2015-05-13T15:15:19` into `2015-05-13T15%3A15%3A19`, which you should be able to read in and parse accordingly.

Comment: Actually, try passing your parameter explicitly as a querystring value `/YourAction?modification_date={your-date-time-with-colons}`.